# Questions about creating a JavaScript MGRS grid

Tags: java, javascript, openlayers

I basically need a reality check on several points.  For my browser-based map application, I need an MGRS grid.  There is an existing question about MGRS grid overlays with OpenLayers, which is exactly what I want, but there wasn't really a satisfactory answer, so I am trying again but with some additional points.  I am willing to create the points that might used to draw line strings on the server-side, pass them to the GUI, then extend OpenLayers' Graticule to use those points.  With that in mind, here are my questions:

1. Is there an existing Java library for calculating MGRS grid points?
2. Is there (despite finding no such thing so far) an existing
   JavaScript solution for creating an MGRS grid?  Ultimately I need to
   show 1K/1K squares.  It seems that I can fake it at the 100,000
   meter square level with OpenLayers' existing graticule (Setting the
   intervals to six degrees), but as I zoom in, and trying to set the
   intervals to mimic 1k/1k squares, the grid does not look accurate.
3. Instead of drawing line strings, it would be nice if the grid was
   made up of actual square objects that could be referenced and, say,
   highlighted or assigned a background image to display the
   designator.  That's where I really need a reality check.  What would
   the performance be like in a browser-based application?  I ask this
   because some co-workers have expressed skepticism about this idea
   performance-wise.

Comment: I'd like to know this too...did you ever find an answer?